# Is it legal to have a C++ struct member point to another member inside it

Tags: c++

Say I have a struct like this. Is it legal C++ to have a member of the struct point to another member inside it? How are these stored?

```cpp
struct Foo {
    int m1{};
    int m2{};
    int* pint{};
    std::string str{};
    const char* pstr{};
};
```

I'm setting the members first, and then the pointers. Is this legal?

```
Foo a {
    .m1 = 10,
    .m2 = 15,
    .str = "Hello, Earth!"
};

a.pint = &a.m1;
a.pstr = a.str.c_str();
```

I'm setting the pointers first, and then the members. Is this legal?

```
Foo a {};

a.pint = &a.m1;
a.pstr = a.str.c_str();
a.m1 = 10,
a.m2 = 15,
a.str = "Hello, Earth!"
```

I checked on [Godbolt.org](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAM1QDsCBlZAQwBtMQBGAFlJvoCqAZ0wAFAB4gA5AAYppAFZdSrZrVDIApACYAQjt2kR7ZATx1KmWugDCqVgFcAtrRDbSV9ABk8tTADlnACNMYhBuAE5SAAdUIUJzWjtHFzcYuIS6Hz9ApxCwyKNMEzM6BgJmYgJk51d3Y0xTRPLKgmyA4NDwqKEKqprU%2Br623w68rsiASiNUB2JkDikdAGZfZEcsAGpNZZtzXuJMZicd7E0ZAEFzi4OHU02AMVRUbYB2fUvNr83fAk2nTiad5AgAiOw%2BF2%2BP3o/20QP0rzBywhUN%2BACpNtFfvDQeDrlDeugQCADr5gJsDjjEXjPt80LReptkAhKhjopTgdTkddcdzLtcni9gJgCAA1NgOTAQSZvFHfQWbZiy/FQ74AOgB22WIM2nBkpBVqs2Gu0Wp1nAArAbaUa1QczdttNoABLFVioUibbCtBBgMA6OE2t5IuVfZhqrEwnY6nQANnDAJpkO%2B4fZBGIDvDBzVyAA%2BgdpUnDZtDgQ5rRFUXqfzLgqnBhc4cqKErAsIIK44qZTigwnOA69TIk1CE6bo7qLUO%2Bcmw3b0w6A67WO7PQBZZ60P0BotB0vlyvT3E1m4EIkgOLpo4nbSxzaoaKhZhEYg7GyviCE4kXw7HTuzAieh2N5dsqQb/lqb67I62gAiA3wBhBr6Khq/ZfK%2BSFgEsFo2JuSxBlC6FQQGTjaHBaFOohUGjvBuwYVhOGYcWBG0URTqRgQcEIYRNibGiqa/JRPGMdhuFMTRkE8QGBxkVxLE8Vm86CZswkMXhM6qtx0HMqyICyRJyFphmmkqaJ05QnuxAVv%2BVZgseAlOMwvjSqBVxBgqzD9vCmzCmKEpSt2XKho8zyKmO7yKp5gXFp%2BKDgZpHlKSZjFmd89boI2mDNoctBth5kzDt8MVoA4fzxZ5cnKfRplBUVcUVcwY4VUlSyHvyiJSNMrDSBa8iuLI8ioNIb56AYFKzPMmCOssnDyBx/WTNMADWIDLMsaqrRtm1bbGKjSNwvXSHIpCDVI8hCCA%2BpzXI0xwLASBoE4WLsGQFAQA9T1dOsajAJw2gyPqVB4KwBChOdEBBId8hBL4lQAJ7SDNpAPU4VgEAA8rQrDw/1pBYA56jsJDuN4IcTQAG6YOdOOYOIjQlYsR2/MUROsHgQTEHDdhYET6Z4E4CMdXwdCMCwhM8ELggiBIRNKJwKjfSgBgGCobPnZA0z3qUDLSAAtDrhLRloI16H9mw62jyxncUjRa5Y1gDK4cueO0uT5MosTxFrDvuxkWsu50YRyw0TRlMM3tB9bIe0C0VT%2B%2BMgdGGH9i1MovStHHbucNMQjjQsXCdd1B04yd4gAByxjrsbcEyqjqLq2hqjIjebBAuCECQU1y5sdiPUDoSdzKw36Hos2QwtpDLat61bTPq07V1Uj7aQfVHSdZ0XaQV2C7diDniV0QleQlDvX3CeYPgz7KPwItsBw4vX8IYiSDjADuHPRALBdSD1y9EydKz9hfoQBAmwy4VyrjXb69dG6N1HvNJaK01qz1nrtReRdV7SHXpdMeX9tDoIGpgzeODSAU2IPECw3AgA%3D%3D), and it seems to work even at the highest optimization levels, but wanted to make sure it was legal C++ lest the UB kraken devour my program.

**Is there a way** I can aggregate initialize the pointers inline to the members of the struct? Something like this?

```
Foo a {
    .m1 = 10,
    .m2 = 15,
    .pint = // address to m2?
    .str = "Hello, Earth!",
    .pstr = // something.c_str()?
};
```

**P.S.** How do I phrase this question, looking for struct member pointing to internal member (and variations) didn't yield any useful results.

**Edit:** I know copy/move is broken for this. A request to the people who answer. If possible, please point me to the specification so that I can develop a habit of reading and interpreting it properly.

Comment: This is legal, but you do have to be careful. What happens when someone creates a copy or move of a `Foo`? It's significantly safer to turn this into a full-fledged class with copy/move constructors/assignments that ensure the pointers are updated correctly.

Comment: I won't be copying or moving, this struct has information that is taken as argument-reference to a function (say `f`), and then discarded (by me, not `f`).

Comment: Also if I may ask, how do I know this is correct (for future questions I might have as I keep learning C++), is there something I can read? I hear the spec is pretty dry, and costs a fortune to get access to, none of which are really straightforward for a student.

Comment: The C++ standard draft: http://eel.is/c++draft/ . This is practically the same as the actual standard. See also https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/links#C.2B.2B_Language_and_library_references for links to specific standard versions. The thing to note here is that these are not the actual ISO standard documents, but are the last draft before the actual document. Draft -> published standard is basically just editorial changes, so you can practically treat these drafts as the actual standard.

Comment: It is legal but already semantically broken because str.c_str() is potentially invalid after assigning a string long enough to necessitate a re-allocation. Make that a function returning the str.c_str() du jour. This is why in C++ you have your data members private and handle access through an interface which maintains the invariants (the guarantees the class makes).

Comment: Is that initialization syntax legal C++?  Doesn't look  like c++ to me, looks like C.  Maybe some compilers allow it...

Comment: Never tried but you can consider using pointer-to-member ` const char* Foo::* pstr;` in this case there will be no confusion that the pointer is an offset with respect to `this`.

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica, thanks for the input! I'm aware of that. Was wondering if it was legal, since after a move/copy, the pointer-to-int might not get updated "properly". Since it works, I assume these are internally stored as offsets into the struct (if it's even present in the final binary)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the comment

> no, the members always point to other members, if at all.

I would suggest changing the member variables `pint` and `pstr` from being pointers to objects to pointers to member variables.

```
struct Foo {
    int m1{};
    int m2{};
    std::string str{};
    int Foo::* pint{nullptr};
    std::string Foo::* pstr{nullptr};
};
```

Then, you can use the default copy constructor and copy assignment operator without any problem. The following should work.

```
Foo a {10, 15, "Hello, Earth!", &Foo::m1, &Foo::str};

std::cout << a.*(a.pint) << std::endl;
std::cout << a.*(a.pstr) << std::endl;

// Default copy constructor works fine.
Foo b = a;
std::cout << b.*(b.pint) << std::endl;
std::cout << b.*(b.pstr) << std::endl;

// Default copy assignment works fine.
Foo c;
c = a;
std::cout << c.*(c.pint) << std::endl;
std::cout << c.*(c.pstr) << std::endl;
```

See it working at https://ideone.com/qE1WVn.

---

Re:

> Could you also answer the last part of the question please (aggregate initialize the pointers inline to the members of the struct)?

You may also use

```
struct Foo {
    int m1{};
    int m2{};
    std::string str{};
    int Foo::* pint{&Foo::m1};
    std::string Foo::* pstr{&Foo::str};
};
```

and

```
Foo a {
    .m1 = 10,
    .m2 = 15,
    .str = "Hello, Earth!",
    .pint = &Foo::m2,
    .pstr = &Foo::str
};
```

Comment: +1 That's prefect! Also thanks for introducing me to the `Foo::*` syntax! I never knew it existed! What's it called? So it should be safe to return this struct from a function (via move/copy). Could you also answer the last part of the question please (aggregate initialize the pointers inline to the members of the struct)?

Comment: @B_Dex_Float that syntax is called "pointers to member variables". Yes, it is save to return function. The answer is yes to the last question.

Comment: thanks for the reply! It works, but I wanted to know the syntax, turns out it's pretty straightforward. https://godbolt.org/z/ze459cYEa. I wasn't sure if a variable was defined in it's own "scope of definition". Is that legal?

Comment: @B_Dex_Float, the linked code still uses `int* pint` instead of `int Foo::* pint`. Also, don't know what you mean by the last statement.

Comment: I meant if I could do `Foo a { .pint = &a.m1 }`, using the variable name itself in the variable. "the linked code still uses", yes my bad! I did correct in my code that raised this question in the first place. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

This is legal, but the default copy/move operations are broken.

Either add

```
Foo(Foo const&)= delete;
Foo(Foo&&)=delete;
Foo&operator=(Foo const&)= delete;
Foo&operator=(Foo&&)=delete;
```

or implement them to do something sensible.

Comment: Could you also let me know if there's a way for the last part (aggregate initialization to an internal member)? Or is it not possible?

Comment: @B_Dex_Float Is it ever likely that `pint` can point to an object that is not a member variable of the `struct`? I am guessing that the answer is no. In that case, you are better off making `pint` to be a pointer to a member variable, not just any object.

Comment: @RSahu, no, the members always point to other members, if at all.